# Compresing large files with gzip in python

Tags: python, gzip

I searched how to compress a file in python, and found an answer that was basically as described below:

```
with open(input_file, 'rb') as f_in, gzip.open(output_file, 'wb') as f_out:
    f_out.write(f_in.read())
```

It works readily with a 1GB file.  But I plan on compressing files up to 200 GB.

Are there any considerations I need to take into account?  Is there a different way I should be doing it with large files like that?

The files are binary `.img` files (exports of a block device; usually with empty space at the end, thus the compression works wonderfully).

Comment: Also, this is reading the files into the python interpreter and then outputting the files.  You could simply write a script that just calls gzip on the files themselves and let the operating system deal with all the problems.

Comment: @PaulBrennan I have to do it in python because this is part of an API and it needs to report progress to the frontend as it executes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will read the entire file into memory, causing problems for you if you don't have 200G available!

You may be able to simply pipe the file through gzip, avoiding Python which will handle doing the work in chunks

```sh
% gzip -c myfile.img > myfile.img.gz
```

Otherwise you should read the file in chunks (picking a large block size may provide some benefit)

```py
BLOCK_SIZE = 8192

with open(myfile, "rb") as f_in, gzip.open(output_file, 'wb') as f_out:
    while True:
        content = f_in.read(BLOCK_SIZE)
        if not content:
            break
        f_out.write(content)
```

Comment: Great answer. I think shutil's copyfileobj is slightly more readable. Here's an example. copyfileobj can also take an optional argument for a buffer size https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html#examples-of-usage

Comment: Oh that's clever (and better, concise!); you should add it as an answer!

Comment: I probably could do it without python, but it's serving as a backend api for managing the files, thus it needs to be able to report the progress.  I was going to do this by calculating how much it's processed out of the original file size.  I'll try your solution.